# MongoDB - Many-to-Many-Relationship (Special Case)

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Should I store an embedded document multiple times in MongoDB or should I only store it once and link to it using it‘s ID?

I want to accomplish a „Many-to-Many-Relationship“ and I only have to update these embedded documents **once a year**.

Which of the both option fits better?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you only have to update the embedded documents one a year, it means that the read operation is going to be used much more than the write operation.

So, for optimizing read operations, "references" should be avoid.

The only remaining concern here is whether the embedded documents are large (size) or not and they are frequently duplicated or not. If not, feel free to use embedded documents, because that is the natural power of MongoDB.